# How to combine string and numeric arrays in Python for csv output

Tags: python, numpy, csv

I'm writing a program in Python 3.

What we want to do

```
import numpy as np

# vals a numeric array of size [3,5]
vals = np.array([.
    [ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0],
    [ 50.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 250.0],
    [100.0, 200.0, 300.0, 400.0, 500.0])
])
# String array of size [3] vals
strs = ['str1','str2','str3',]
```

I want to write out the following to a csv file. In other words, I want to export the data so that there are 3 rows and 6 columns in the csv file.
csv output Ideal

```
str1, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0
str2, 50.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 250.0
str3, 100.0, 200.0, 300.0, 400.0, 500.0
```

What I've done
If you only want to write out a numerical array, you can use
Code 1

```
import csv
with open('out.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writers(vals)
```

However, I cannot insert a string array into this left column.
The method I just tried is to output the same csv with whatever information is in the string array at least first, code 1 followed by
Code 2

```
strs2 = [strs] # Without this, one cell will contain one character.
with open('out.csv', 'a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writers(strs2)
```

but this will only output csv if the
csv output Current

```
1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0
50.0, 100.0, 150.0, 200.0, 250.0
100.0, 200.0, 300.0, 400.0, 500.0
str1, str2, str3
```

The result is as follows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this with:

```
strs = ['str1','str2','str3'].
Do it like this: strs = np.array

strs = np.array([['str1'],['str2'],['str3']])
csvdata = np.hstack([strs,vals])
```

You can use the previous one to write the resulting csvdata to a csv file.